# How to limit the child process in perl?

Tags: perl, fork

I have written a script which includes generation of gcov in parallel.I succeeded in that but it is creating 17 child process at a time.But i want to create only 6 child processes at a time,the 7th child should create after 1child process terminate.

```
sub gcov_parallel()
  2 {
  3     print "Generating Gcov...\n";
  4     my $kid;
  5     my $pid;
  6     @list = (@iucall,@iurcall_init,@iurcall_term,@iurcall_uti,@nob,@nobcch,@nobcell,@nobrrc,@nobcall,@rnccall,@cellin
    fo,@rnccom,@cellrrm,@uerrm,@uerrc,@uecall,@iupcded);
  7     my $len_list = scalar(@list);
  8     my $maxlen =0;
  9     my $count = 0;
 10     my $process = 0;
 11     $total_components = scalar(@comp_list);
 12
 13     for(my $comp_count=0; $comp_count < $len_list ; ($comp_count=$comp_count+$no_of_machines))
 14     {
 15         #limiting child process to 6
 16         if($process == 6)
 17         {
 18             $pid = wait();
 19             $process=$process-1;
 20         }
 21         else
 22         {
 23             $pid = fork();
 24             if($pid eq 0)
 25             {
 26                 for(my $files_count = 0; $files_count < $no_of_machines; $files_count++)
 27                 {
 28                     $count =  $files_count+$comp_count;
 29                     if($count < $len_list)
 30                     {
 31                         chomp($list[$count]);
 32                         my @list_gcda =`ls $list[$count]/*.gcda | sort`;
&generate_gcov("$list[$count]",@list_gcda);
 34                     }
 35                 }
 36                 wait();
 37                 exit;
 38             }
 39             $process=$process+1;
 40         }
 41     }
 42     do
 43     {
 44         $kid = waitpid(-1, 0);
 45     }while $kid > 0;
 46 }

But i observed while running the script it is skipping files while generating gcov.
```

Comment: List1 contains.. array of components @iucall,@uerrc etc... Each component array contains files.for The 1st 6 components working fine but after that it is skipping alternate components

Comment: your `wait()`call in line 36 seems dubious: lines 26-35 constitute the code for the child processes, right? none of these has to wait for any other child processes, simply because it has no child processes. thus it blocks and consequently the parent process won't receive any termination signal. i wonder whether your script terminates at all.

Answer (score 7):

I think you could use [Paralel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3A%3AForkManager) to do this.

There is a [good tutorial on PerlMonks about Paralel::ForkManager](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=291446).

It could be this simple:

```
my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new( 6 );
   foreach my $command (@commands) {
      $manager->start and next;
      system( $command );
      $manager->finish;
   };
```

Comment: user only wants 6 child processes, not 17. Can't make edit since it's too few characters.  Good answer, though.

Comment: But the final result is not accurate, if all the 6 child process is using the same temp directory but not accessing the same file,will it create any problem?